# Unable to install eth-dagger to node.js project

Tags: node.js, scrypt

https://docs.matic.network/dagger/getting-started/#support

I am attempting to install this library to a node.js project. I am a junior developer and quite lost, so please explain things as though I were a child.

I have tried reinstalling node, ensuring git was installed and the right version, updating any number of computer functions but no matter what it fails.

My process: 
npm init
npm install eth-dagger --save <--- this is where it fails each time

I can supply logs as people want, the log for the error is over 29 thousand lines long so not sure i can just past the entire thing, the main error I see is

Error c2661: 'v8:value::ToObject':no overload function takes 0 arguments \node_modules\scrypt\build\scrypt.vcxproj

I found some information online that scrypt was no longer maintained and outdated, but is there a way to work around that or install dagger anyways?

First 20 or so lines of the log:

2 info using npm@6.13.4

3 info using node@v12.14.1

4 verbose npm-session acc67846f68ba194

5 silly install loadCurrentTree

6 silly install readLocalPackageData

7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@maticnetwork%2feth-dagger 18ms (from cache)

8 silly pacote tag manifest for @maticnetwork/eth-dagger@latest fetched in 30ms

9 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 1822ms

10 silly install loadIdealTree

11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree

12 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 15ms

13 silly install loadShrinkwrap

14 timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 482ms

15 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree

16 silly resolveWithNewModule @maticnetwork/eth-dagger@0.0.1 checking installable status

17 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/web3 156ms (from cache)

18 silly pacote version manifest for web3@1.0.0-beta.34 fetched in 159ms

19 silly resolveWithNewModule web3@1.0.0-beta.34 checking installable status

20 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-ext 44ms (from cache)

21 silly pacote range manifest for fs-ext@~0.5.0 fetched in 47ms

22 silly resolveWithNewModule fs-ext@0.5.0 checking installable status

23 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/web3-eth 45ms (from cache)

24 silly pacote version manifest for web3-eth@1.0.0-beta.34 fetched in 48ms

25 silly resolveWithNewModule web3-eth@1.0.0-beta.34 checking installable status

[A screencap of the end area of the error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA8ae.png)

Comment: Hi, can you add the first few lines of the error logs, like 10-20 lines is fine.

Comment: Added stuff to the post